# Control where Uploadify displays queue items and progress

Tags: jquery, uploadify

How can I control where uploadify displays queue items and progress indicators?

I would like to move them away from the upload button.

Uploadify generates html-items with this the class "uploadifyQueueItem" for items in the queue, but they are just put right after the uploadify object, as far as I can tell.

Comment: If I remmeber correctly, Uploadify replaces the DIV with it's own HTML (?). Therfore I think youare not able to choose where this will be dispalyed. But I might bewrong... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally in your html you have

```
<div id="fileQueue"></div>
```

and in your uploadify params:

```
'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
```

Thats all there is to it. You can put that div anywhere in your page you want.